# GPU process exited unexpectedly when opening chrome

Tags: drivers, graphics, 22.04, google-chrome

This happened after I installed ubuntu updates recently, like last 3 `apt install upgrade`. I am running 22.04.3 on Thinkpad. Every time I open chrome, it shows gpu error on terminal:

```
❯ google-chrome
[62841:62841:0831/070236.465170:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(956)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[62841:62841:0831/070236.651634:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(956)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[62841:62841:0831/070236.825423:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(956)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[62841:62841:0831/070236.994207:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(956)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[62841:62841:0831/070237.161538:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(956)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[62841:62841:0831/070237.329297:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(956)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
```

Both ubuntu and chrome (Google Chrome 116.0.5845.140) updated.

Because of this issue, OpenGL and GPU are disabled on chrome and I cannot open websites that utilize them like Figma. I was noticing upgrades on graphics driver/mesa dri or something.

This is my graphics information if necessary:

```
[sudo] password for fsevenm: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:177 memory:e9000000-e9ffffff memory:a0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```